# Таблицы всех пользователей (1000) в одной базе или разных?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Я думаю с подобным вопросом уже сталкивались хостинги.

У меня вопрос следующего содержания:
Есть хостинг услуг для пользователей (их будет порядка 10 тысяч), по хранению и обработке информации на MSSQL2017 или PostgreSQL.

Есть 1000 пользователей на сервер, у каждого пользователя есть по 4 своих таблицы (1000пользователей*4таблицы=4000таблиц). Количество записей в каждой таблице порядка 100 000.

"Таблица 1" - (id-int, Data-nvarcha(max),
"Таблица 2" - (id-int, Data-int),
"Таблица 3" - (id-int, Data-Float),
"Tаблица 4" - (id-int, Data-bool).

В базу будут добавляться данные и удаляться наиболее старшие записи.

Вопрос по производительности: Лучше Создать каждому пользователю по 4 таблице в каждой базе, или по 4 таблице каждому пользователю в единой базе?

Comment: А каким образом пользователи получают доступ к таблицам, подключаясь непосредственно к БД или всегда через какие нибудь ваши программные механизмы (вроде api или пользовательского web интерфейса). А то может и не делать вообще отдельные таблицы ...

Comment: Вопрос в скорости работы или в безопасности?

Comment: Пользователи будут получать доступ через API, в MSSQL будут готовые процедуры... Вопрос скорее по производительности БД... Если есть варианты по смене БД, то вполне могу сменить... Еще все на стадии разработки.

Comment: 10000 записей для БД - это полная ерунда

Comment: Пока что из описания получается одна или две таблицы на всех пользователей: таблица юзеров и таблица данных с тремя колонками (плюс колонки ключа и т. п.) Опишите подробнее, какая именно информацию будет храниться.

Comment: Как я понял, 10 тысяч - это про клиентов хостинга. Где хранить пользовательские данные - конечно давать им создавать свои базы. Если речь о данных по учёту ваших клиентов - это отдельное приложение(вполне рядовое) в одной базе. Не нужно создавать отдельные множества таблиц, а тем более баз каждому клиенту. Храните все данные в общем датасете. В общем одна таблица клиентов с аутентификационными данными, а остальные таблицы(услуги, домены и т.п.) ссылаются на pk таблицы клиентов.

Answer (score 1):

Хранение в виде отдельных таблиц и отдельных баз несет огромные накладные расходы. Прежде всего, на кэширование планов выполнения. `SELECT` написанный для одного пользователя не будет разделять план выполнения с точно такми же `SELECT`-ом для другого. Будет тормозить, особенно на холодном старте.

К тому же отдельные базы или таблицы будут тупо выдавливать друг друга из кэша, и у вас будет состояние постоянного холодного старта :)

Оба ваши варианта, к сожалению, плохи.

---

То, что вы разрабатываете, называется multi-tenant приложение.

Если

- Структура таблиц для каждого пользователя одинаковая (поля те же, типы данных те же)
- Количество данных для каждого пользователя примерно одинаковое (нет жестких перекосов вида пара строк для одного - миллионы для другого)

то нет никакого смысла хранить данные пользователей в раздельных таблицах или раздельных базах. Добавьте в каждую таблицу поле UserID (а лучше - TenantID, это стандартная терминология):

```
"Таблица 1" - (tenantid-int, id-int, Data-nvarchar(max)),
"Таблица 2" - (tenantid-int, id-int, Data-int),
"Таблица 3" - (tenantid-int, id-int, Data-Float),
"Tаблица 4" - (tenantid-int, id-int, Data-bool).
```

... и добавьте во все запросы фильтры `WHERE TenantID = @CurrentUserID`.

Если нужен более строгий и надежный фильтр - используйте Row Level Security вместо ручного `WHERE`.

И все будет работать без тысяч таблиц и тысяч отдельных баз, на 4 обычных таблицах.

Если перекос по данным есть - то выносите отдельных проблемных (крупных) клиентов в отдельные базы, и роутите туда SQL запросы, с сохранением всей структуры.

Это стандартная схема для Multi-tenant SaaS, у [MS есть есть подробная документация по архитектуре](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns#f-multi-tenant-app-with-a-single-multi-tenant-database) и [готовый пример поверх Azure SQL Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/WingtipTicketsSaaS-MultiTenantDb).

Comment: Если все будет в одной БД храниться, то предлагаете для всех пользователей вести в совместных таблицах ? Если суммарное количество записей в каждой таблице выростет до 100 000зап*1000пользователей=100млн записей! Может быстрее работать БД будет с 1000 пользв*4табл?

Comment: @Antonio да, я предлагаю хранить данные всех пользователей в совместных таблицах. Это самый эффективный вариант в вашем случае. У меня сейчас на проде есть таблицы по 100m записей с разбиением о tenantid. Все отлично работает. Нет, база с 4000 таблиц работать быстрее не будет, наборот, будет работать намного медленнее из-за невозможности переиспользовать планы выполнения. Да ещё и при добавлении пользователя вам придется создавать таблицы на лету, а это глобальный лок на всю базу. Кроме того, она будет реально неподдерживаемой, следующий dba вас проклянёт :)

Comment: попробую создать 4 таблички, создать ключи, наполнить их по максимуму и погонять по полной )

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, вы неправильно понимаете принцип баз данных.
Таблица это сборник данных("отдельный файл"), где каждому отдельному пользователю отводится (горизонтальная) стока.

Пример структуры базы данных:

[image: Пример структуры]

Пример структуры моей таблицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Если вам нужно, чтобы пользователи могли редактировать типы данных-тогда отдельные таблицы
- Если если пользователи могут менять количество таблиц тогда базы
- Если у вас будет хранится какая-то типизирования информация о пользователях, которой они могут обратятся, тогда тогда общая таблица. И при запросе данных требуйте два поля ID и ключ

Comment: Судя по всему я не так выразился ) Есть 1000 пользователей, у каждого пользователя есть по 4 своих таблицы (1000*4=4000таблиц). Количество записей в каждой таблице порядка 100 000. Таблица 1 - (id-int,Data-nvarcha(max), Таблица 2 (id-int,Data- int), Таблица 3 - (id-int,Data-Float), таблица 4 - (id-int,Data-bool). В базу будут добавляться данные и удаляться наиболее старшие записи. Вопрос по производительности: Лучше Создать каждому (1000) пользователю по 4 таблице в каждой базе, или по 4 таблице в единой базе?

Comment: На мой взгляд, отдельные базы